# Can't identify or stylize brushed (i.e. selected) elements in d3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, data-visualization

I am following two tutorials:

1. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045
2. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4560481

But I cannot seem to identify or stylize the selected (i.e. brushed) elements. I suspect some type of scope issue.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node .selected {
  stroke: #ff0;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.2;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(0.1)
    .linkStrength(0.1)
    .charge(-50)
    .linkDistance(25)
    .size([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", window.innerWidth)
    .attr("height", window.innerHeight);

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.append("g").attr("class", "link")
    .selectAll("line")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .style("stroke-width", 1);

  var node = svg.append("g").attr("class", "node")
    .selectAll("circle")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5);

  var brush = svg.append("g").attr("class", "brush")
    .call(d3.svg.brush()
      .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, window.innerWidth]))
      .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, window.innerHeight]))
      .on("brush", function () {    // Here be dragons
        var extent = d3.event.target.extent();
        node.classed("selected", function (d) {
          return extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0]
                 && extent[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < extent[1][1];
        });
  }));

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

  });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the graph.json:

```
{"nodes":[{"x":444,"y":275},{"x":378,"y":324},{"x":478,"y":278},{"x":471,"y":256},{"x":382,"y":269},{"x":371,"y":247},{"x":359,"y":276},{"x":364,"y":302},{"x":400,"y":330},{"x":388,"y":298},{"x":524,"y":296},{"x":570,"y":243},{"x":552,"y":159},{"x":502,"y":287},{"x":511,"y":313},{"x":513,"y":265},{"x":602,"y":132},{"x":610,"y":90},{"x":592,"y":91},{"x":575,"y":89},{"x":607,"y":73},{"x":591,"y":68},{"x":574,"y":73},{"x":589,"y":149},{"x":620,"y":205},{"x":621,"y":230},{"x":589,"y":234},{"x":602,"y":223},{"x":548,"y":188},{"x":532,"y":196},{"x":548,"y":114},{"x":575,"y":174},{"x":497,"y":250},{"x":576,"y":196},{"x":504,"y":201},{"x":494,"y":186},{"x":482,"y":199},{"x":505,"y":219},{"x":486,"y":216},{"x":590,"y":306},{"x":677,"y":169},{"x":657,"y":258},{"x":667,"y":205},{"x":552,"y":227},{"x":518,"y":173},{"x":473,"y":125},{"x":796,"y":260},{"x":731,"y":272},{"x":642,"y":288},{"x":576,"y":269},{"x":605,"y":187},{"x":559,"y":289},{"x":544,"y":356},{"x":505,"y":365},{"x":579,"y":289},{"x":619,"y":282},{"x":574,"y":329},{"x":664,"y":306},{"x":627,"y":304},{"x":643,"y":327},{"x":664,"y":348},{"x":665,"y":327},{"x":653,"y":317},{"x":650,"y":338},{"x":622,"y":321},{"x":633,"y":338},{"x":647,"y":357},{"x":718,"y":362},{"x":636,"y":240},{"x":640,"y":227},{"x":617,"y":249},{"x":631,"y":254},{"x":566,"y":213},{"x":713,"y":322},{"x":716,"y":298},{"x":666,"y":241},{"x":627,"y":355}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":0},{"source":2,"target":0},{"source":3,"target":0},{"source":3,"target":2},{"source":4,"target":0},{"source":5,"target":0},{"source":6,"target":0},{"source":7,"target":0},{"source":8,"target":0},{"source":9,"target":0},{"source":11,"target":10},{"source":11,"target":3},{"source":11,"target":2},{"source":11,"target":0},{"source":12,"target":11},{"source":13,"target":11},{"source":14,"target":11},{"source":15,"target":11},{"source":17,"target":16},{"source":18,"target":16},{"source":18,"target":17},{"source":19,"target":16},{"source":19,"target":17},{"source":19,"target":18},{"source":20,"target":16},{"source":20,"target":17},{"source":20,"target":18},{"source":20,"target":19},{"source":21,"target":16},{"source":21,"target":17},{"source":21,"target":18},{"source":21,"target":19},{"source":21,"target":20},{"source":22,"target":16},{"source":22,"target":17},{"source":22,"target":18},{"source":22,"target":19},{"source":22,"target":20},{"source":22,"target":21},{"source":23,"target":16},{"source":23,"target":17},{"source":23,"target":18},{"source":23,"target":19},{"source":23,"target":20},{"source":23,"target":21},{"source":23,"target":22},{"source":23,"target":12},{"source":23,"target":11},{"source":24,"target":23},{"source":24,"target":11},{"source":25,"target":24},{"source":25,"target":23},{"source":25,"target":11},{"source":26,"target":24},{"source":26,"target":11},{"source":26,"target":16},{"source":26,"target":25},{"source":27,"target":11},{"source":27,"target":23},{"source":27,"target":25},{"source":27,"target":24},{"source":27,"target":26},{"source":28,"target":11},{"source":28,"target":27},{"source":29,"target":23},{"source":29,"target":27},{"source":29,"target":11},{"source":30,"target":23},{"source":31,"target":30},{"source":31,"target":11},{"source":31,"target":23},{"source":31,"target":27},{"source":32,"target":11},{"source":33,"target":11},{"source":33,"target":27},{"source":34,"target":11},{"source":34,"target":29},{"source":35,"target":11},{"source":35,"target":34},{"source":35,"target":29},{"source":36,"target":34},{"source":36,"target":35},{"source":36,"target":11},{"source":36,"target":29},{"source":37,"target":34},{"source":37,"target":35},{"source":37,"target":36},{"source":37,"target":11},{"source":37,"target":29},{"source":38,"target":34},{"source":38,"target":35},{"source":38,"target":36},{"source":38,"target":37},{"source":38,"target":11},{"source":38,"target":29},{"source":39,"target":25},{"source":40,"target":25},{"source":41,"target":24},{"source":41,"target":25},{"source":42,"target":41},{"source":42,"target":25},{"source":42,"target":24},{"source":43,"target":11},{"source":43,"target":26},{"source":43,"target":27},{"source":44,"target":28},{"source":44,"target":11},{"source":45,"target":28},{"source":47,"target":46},{"source":48,"target":47},{"source":48,"target":25},{"source":48,"target":27},{"source":48,"target":11},{"source":49,"target":26},{"source":49,"target":11},{"source":50,"target":49},{"source":50,"target":24},{"source":51,"target":49},{"source":51,"target":26},{"source":51,"target":11},{"source":52,"target":51},{"source":52,"target":39},{"source":53,"target":51},{"source":54,"target":51},{"source":54,"target":49},{"source":54,"target":26},{"source":55,"target":51},{"source":55,"target":49},{"source":55,"target":39},{"source":55,"target":54},{"source":55,"target":26},{"source":55,"target":11},{"source":55,"target":16},{"source":55,"target":25},{"source":55,"target":41},{"source":55,"target":48},{"source":56,"target":49},{"source":56,"target":55},{"source":57,"target":55},{"source":57,"target":41},{"source":57,"target":48},{"source":58,"target":55},{"source":58,"target":48},{"source":58,"target":27},{"source":58,"target":57},{"source":58,"target":11},{"source":59,"target":58},{"source":59,"target":55},{"source":59,"target":48},{"source":59,"target":57},{"source":60,"target":48},{"source":60,"target":58},{"source":60,"target":59},{"source":61,"target":48},{"source":61,"target":58},{"source":61,"target":60},{"source":61,"target":59},{"source":61,"target":57},{"source":61,"target":55},{"source":62,"target":55},{"source":62,"target":58},{"source":62,"target":59},{"source":62,"target":48},{"source":62,"target":57},{"source":62,"target":41},{"source":62,"target":61},{"source":62,"target":60},{"source":63,"target":59},{"source":63,"target":48},{"source":63,"target":62},{"source":63,"target":57},{"source":63,"target":58},{"source":63,"target":61},{"source":63,"target":60},{"source":63,"target":55},{"source":64,"target":55},{"source":64,"target":62},{"source":64,"target":48},{"source":64,"target":63},{"source":64,"target":58},{"source":64,"target":61},{"source":64,"target":60},{"source":64,"target":59},{"source":64,"target":57},{"source":64,"target":11},{"source":65,"target":63},{"source":65,"target":64},{"source":65,"target":48},{"source":65,"target":62},{"source":65,"target":58},{"source":65,"target":61},{"source":65,"target":60},{"source":65,"target":59},{"source":65,"target":57},{"source":65,"target":55},{"source":66,"target":64},{"source":66,"target":58},{"source":66,"target":59},{"source":66,"target":62},{"source":66,"target":65},{"source":66,"target":48},{"source":66,"target":63},{"source":66,"target":61},{"source":66,"target":60},{"source":67,"target":57},{"source":68,"target":25},{"source":68,"target":11},{"source":68,"target":24},{"source":68,"target":27},{"source":68,"target":48},{"source":68,"target":41},{"source":69,"target":25},{"source":69,"target":68},{"source":69,"target":11},{"source":69,"target":24},{"source":69,"target":27},{"source":69,"target":48},{"source":69,"target":41},{"source":70,"target":25},{"source":70,"target":69},{"source":70,"target":68},{"source":70,"target":11},{"source":70,"target":24},{"source":70,"target":27},{"source":70,"target":41},{"source":70,"target":58},{"source":71,"target":27},{"source":71,"target":69},{"source":71,"target":68},{"source":71,"target":70},{"source":71,"target":11},{"source":71,"target":48},{"source":71,"target":41},{"source":71,"target":25},{"source":72,"target":26},{"source":72,"target":27},{"source":72,"target":11},{"source":73,"target":48},{"source":74,"target":48},{"source":74,"target":73},{"source":75,"target":69},{"source":75,"target":68},{"source":75,"target":25},{"source":75,"target":48},{"source":75,"target":41},{"source":75,"target":70},{"source":75,"target":71},{"source":76,"target":64},{"source":76,"target":65},{"source":76,"target":66},{"source":76,"target":63},{"source":76,"target":62},{"source":76,"target":48},{"source":76,"target":58}]}
```

Running `$('.selected')` in the console with an area highlighted yields only 1 selected element, despite how large the brush area was. Any help would be exceedingly welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you don't have jQuery included in the page, so $ isn't actually the jQuery alias, but I believe is some console shortcut, which returns only a single element.

I haven't had the opportunity to test your example in jsFiddle, but I tested the second link you provided (which also doesn't have jQuery included), and indeed $ returns a single element, but d3.selectAll('.selected') and document.querySelectorAll('.selected') return the correct number of elements. Try using those and see if the problem persists.

The only thing the .selected class is doing is add a stroke: red rule to the selected elements, so it shouldn't be something very spectacular to select those elements.

**Edit**: The $() method (if you're using chrome) is described here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#selector . It returns only the first DOM element which matches your selection. If you want all the elements, use $$ (equivalent of document.querySelectorAll)